# Tabs in a Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, plugins

In this video it looks like Courtney has tabs (Content | Design) in the individual fields in a Matrix. I can't work out how to do this, is it a plugin? It seems a great way of organising the fields for the editor

https://vimeo.com/294976443

Screengrab:

[image: Matrix field with Tabs]

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a plugin, yes. It's [Spoon by Angell & Co](https://plugins.craftcms.com/spoon).

Comment: The [Neo](https://plugins.craftcms.com/neo) plugin also offers the same functionality.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that while Neo offers similar functionality, it does so by requiring you to use an entirely new field type other than "matrix" that isn't part of the core. Where as Spoon and Matrix Mate simply allow you to re-arrange existing matrix fields into tabs.

Removing or disabling Spoon or Matrix Mate wouldn't break your site, but removing Neo would.

Answer (score 1):

Matrixmate is an awesome plugin that allows you to do the tabbing for Matrixes.

That's it's primary focus, and it's free.

https://plugins.craftcms.com/matrixmate

Another awesome thing, is that you configure it with a php file in the config folder. I find this convenient because I easily carry over the feature to other websites that are structured the same way. No logging in to add values to gui fields.